# transform a program to client node

Tags: gazebo, simulation, turtlebot, turtlebot-simulator, turtlebot-gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

help needed!! I have the following program in C language, that takes initial and final pose of a robot and moves it to the final state. I want to simulate the process for a turtlebot in ROS/GAZEBO, so i need to "translate" the program to a client node!!! here is the code:

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void control(double Xinit[3], double Xfinal[3], double u1, double w1) //Η συνάρτηση επιστρέφει τις ταχύτητες u και ω

{
FILE *file;
file = fopen("file.txt","a+");

double f, th, a, x, y, e, p, csa, sna, u2, w2, Xk[3];

double pi=3.141592654;

int g = 3;
int h = 1;
int k = 6;

int i;

x = Xfinal[0] - Xinit[0];  //Το πρώτο στοιχείο του διανύσματος Χfinal αντιστοιχεί στη τελική συντεταγμένη - Χ, ενώ το πρώτο στοιχείο του διανύσματος Χinit αντιστοιχεί στη συντεταγμένη - Χ του ρομπότ κάθε χρονικη στιγμή κατά τη διάρκεια της πορείας του.

y = Xfinal[1] - Xinit[1];  //Το δεύτερο στοιχείο του διανύσματος Χfinal αντιστοιχεί στη τελική συντεταγμένη - Υ, ενώ το δεύτερο στοιχείο του διανύσματος Χinit αντιστοιχεί στη συντεταγμένη - Υ του ρομπότ κάθε χρονικη στιγμή κατά τη διάρκεια της πορείας του.

f = Xfinal[2] - Xinit[2];  //Το τρίτο στοιχείο του διανύσματος Χfinal αντιστοιχεί στο τελικό προσανατολισμό, ενώ το τρίτο στοιχείο του διανύσματος Χinit αντιστοιχεί στο προσανατολισμό του ρομπότ κάθε χρονικη στιγμή κατά τη διάρκεια της πορείας του.

p = atan2(y,x);
p = p*180/pi;

th = Xfinal[2] - p;

a = th - f;

if(a>0)
a=-a;

csa = cos(a*pi/180);
sna = sin(a*pi/180);

e = sqrt(x*x + y*y);

//Υπολογισμός γραμμικής ταχύτητας - u
u2 = u1 + (e*g*csa);

//Υπολογισμός γωνιακής ταχύτητας - ω
w2 = w1 + (k*a + ((g*csa*sna*(a + h*th))/a));

//fprintf(file,"\nDx = %f",x);
//fprintf(file,"\nDy = %f",y);
//fprintf(file,"\nDf = %f",f);

//fprintf(file,"\nth = %f",th);
//fprintf(file,"\na = %f",a);
//fprintf(file,"\ne = %f",e);

fprintf(file,"\n%10.3f",u2);
fprintf(file,"%10.3f",w2);

fclose(file);

for(i=0; i<3; i++)
Xk[i]=0.0;

model(Xk,Xinit,u2,w2,Xfinal);

return;
}

void model(double Xk[3], double Xj[3], double u1, double w1, double Xfinal[3])
//Οι ταχύτητες u και ω, υπολογίζονται στη συνάρτηση control

{
FILE *file;
file = fopen("file.txt","a");

double B[3][2];

double Dt;

double pi=3.141592654;

Dt=0.0005;

B[0][0] = cos(Xj[2]*pi/180);
B[0][1] = 0.0;
B[1][0] = sin(Xj[2]*pi/180);
B[1][1] = 0.0;
B[2][0] = 0.0;
B[2][1] = 1.0;

if(Xj[0] >= Xfinal[0])
Xk[0] = Xj[0] + (B[0][0]*u1 + B[0][1]*w1)*Dt;
else
Xk[0] = Xj[0];

if(Xj[1] >= Xfinal[1])
Xk[1] = Xj[1] + (B[1][0]*u1 + B[1][1]*w1)*Dt;
else
Xk[1] = Xj[1];

if(Xj[2] >= Xfinal[2])
Xk[2] = Xj[2] + (B[2][0]*u1 + B[2][1]*w1)*Dt;
else
Xk[2] = Xj[2];

if(u1==0.0)
exit(0);

fprintf(file,"%10.3f",Xk[0]);
fprintf(file,"%10.3f",Xk[1]);
fprintf(file,"%10.2f",Xk[2]);

u1=0.0;
w1=0.0;

fclose(file);

control(Xk,Xfinal,u1,w1);

return;

}

void main()

{

double Xinit[3], Xfinal[3];

double u,w;

FILE *file;
file = fopen("file.txt","w+");
fprintf(file,"\n     u          w         Xk+1      Yk+1     Thk+1\n");
fprintf(file,"============================================================\n");

u=0.0;
w=0.0;

printf("enter robot's initial state:\n");
printf("X pose:\n");
scanf("%lf", &Xinit[0]);
printf("Y pose:\n");
scanf("%lf", &Xinit[1]);
printf("Theta orientation:\n");
scanf("%lf", &Xinit[2]);

printf("enter robot's final state:\n");
printf("X pose:\n");
scanf("%lf", &Xfinal[0]);
printf("Y pose:\n");
scanf("%lf", &Xfinal[1]);
printf("Theta orientation:\n");
scanf("%lf", &Xfinal[2]);

fclose(file);

control(Xinit,Xfinal,u,w);

return;
}

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32217/transform-a-program-to-client-node/) by [grge](https://answers.ros.org/users/2213/grge/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2012-04-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suggest that you first go through a few basic ROS tutorials [here](http://ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials), including [this](http://ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_navigation/Tutorials/Autonomously%20navigate%20in%20a%20known%20map) tutorial.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1